# Разрешить только создание файла в директории linux

Tags: linux, резервное-копирование, chmod

Возможно ли разрешить в Linux только создание файла, но не его изменение или удаление? Бэкап, куда можно лишь сбрасывать данные, а читать лишь администратору.

Comment: Формулировка "создание, но не изменение" подразумевает, что всё, что можно сделать с файлом — это создать его с нулевой длиной, потому что *любая* запись в него — это изменение.

Answer (score 3):

Думаю вам нужен acl

```
~# apropos setfacl
setfacl (1)          - set file access control lists
~# touch test_file && chmod 700 test_file
~# stat test_file
  File: test_file
  Size: 0               Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: fd02h/64770d    Inode: 266127      Links: 1
Access: (0700/-rwx------)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Context: unconfined_u:object_r:user_tmp_t:s0
Access: 2018-08-29 00:52:52.283387184 +0100
Modify: 2018-08-29 00:52:52.283387184 +0100
Change: 2018-08-29 00:53:26.822119567 +0100
 Birth: -

~# setfacl -m u:lfs:w test_file
~# su lfs
~$ cat test_file
cat: test_file: Permission denied
~$ echo "test line" >> test_file
~$ exit
~# cat test_file
hello world
test line
```